# How do I install Kodos in 12.10?

Tags: tools, regex

In previous Ubuntu version I used [Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/) extensively. But the package has been dropped in 12.10.

It's a neat *regular expression testing tool*. It's hard to find an alternative that is not Windows only (or Air, or uses action script which bails on more complicated RegEx, or works in Wine - well kinda, but not really..., etc.).

So I tried to install Kodos from source, which seems to work (download sourceball and `setup.py`) but it won't run because of missing **PyQT** dependencies (that I can't manage to fulfill with anything install-able trough standard packages). I then tried to install PyQT manually (which seems to require manual install of *SIP* and *QT* too) and instead of `pip` I have to use `configure.py` and `qmake`. It throws error after error at me. I tried to overcome one after another for over an hour but no luck.

It even managed to break Calibre and Music Brains Picard. So I purged all the stuff, reinstalled `python-sip`and `python-qt4` from the standard packages and gave up.

*Has anyone managed to get Kodos running on 12.10? Or any hints on how to do it?*

Comment: Could you post the errors you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get it to work easily. Kodos still uses the very ancient Qt3 which is dropped in Quantal. Debian already dropped it in May. See [Debian bug #604359](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=604359). Quoting:

> One year and a half later, it is about time to remove Qt3 and python-qt3.
>   Please, migrate to the Qt4 version (if existing) or file for removal of your
>   package.

Talk with the developers of Kodos in order to get it fixed. Depending on Qt3 is a dead end nowadays. And that's why installing Qt4 packages isn't helping you.